# Architectural Pattern with Windows Services

Tags: .net, architecture, windows-services, architectural-patterns

I'm newbie and I always write my code simply without any *architecture*, so to speak. I have task to make a small **Windows Service** project (service connects to API every hour, gets some info and write it into eventlog). And I've done it, it works just fine, but I have to think about *architecture* of this project.

So far I have only my *MyNewService.cs* with all needed methods like OnStart, OnTimer etc. but unfortunetly its unacceptable. I know only MVC pattern but I have no idea how to "implement" pattern to project. I mean e.g when I create ASP.NET project, MVC pattern is already there. Moreover, MVC is about some Views and so on, so I'm really confused how it is supposed to work with Windows Services :c but I guess it is possible...

Please help :f

Answer (score 0):

The asp.net core worker service is the way to go.

Here's some good video introduction:

https://youtu.be/PzrTiz_NRKA